# Passing through function to component, REACT

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im new to react and trying to add darkmode/lightmode switch to my site.
I have done this succesfully. However, the switch button to change between dark and light mode only works in app.tsx, this is due to  the  function only works in app.tsx.

So to my question, how do i pass a function to a component in react?
i have tried props etc. but none have worked.

Here is my `app.tsx`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import logo from "./assets/logo.png";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from "./theme";
import { GlobalStyles } from "./global";

function App() {
  
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  function toggleTheme() {
    if (theme === "light") {
      setTheme("dark");
    } else {
      setTheme("light");
    }
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme === "light" ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar/>
        <button onClick={toggleTheme}></button>
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1>linusromland.com</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is my `Navbar.tsx`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import BSNavbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import "./Navbar.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import lightmode from "../../assets/lightmode.svg";
import darkmode from "../../assets/darkmode.svg";

class Navbar extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Navbar" data-testid="Navbar">
        <BSNavbar bg="light" expand="lg">
          <Container className="col-5">
            <BSNavbar.Brand href="/">Linus Romland</BSNavbar.Brand>
            <BSNavbar.Toggle />
            <BSNavbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
              <Nav>
                <Nav.Link href="/" className="text-dark">
                  Home
                </Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link
                  href="https://github.com/linusromland/"
                  className="text-dark"
                >
                  GitHub
                </Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/about" className="text-dark">
                  About
                </Nav.Link>
                <Button variant="light">
                  <img src={lightmode} alt="Darkmode/Lightmode change" />
                </Button>
              </Nav>
            </BSNavbar.Collapse>
          </Container>
        </BSNavbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to pass the function to the Navbar? I see you already have a "Theme toggle" button in your App (below the `<Navbar />`), so why do you want the function in Navbar too?

Comment: @Shahriar: i want to run the function from a button in the navbar. I want to remove the toggle button from the App and move it to the Navbar.

Comment: So it will be better if you describe this in the question. Might be confusing for people seeing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a callback function to your NavBar component and the function will get the App.tsx context

```
        <Navbar toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />
```

then in your component

```
            <Button variant="light" onClick={this.props.toggleTheme}>
              <img src={lightmode} alt="Darkmode/Lightmode change" />
            </Button>
```

Comment: I've tried that, i get the following error:
https://i.imgur.com/No59sCT.png

Comment: @LinusRomland you can solve that using changing class Navbar extends React.Component<any, any> {

Comment: Glad it worked, you should now accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A good use case for provider pattern. Basically, you would create a so-called "provider" component with an internal state to encapsulate your current theme and a function for toggling the theme:

```
import React, { useContext, createContext, useState, useMemo } from 'react'

const SelectThemeContext = createContext()

const SelectThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');

    const toggleTheme = () => if (theme === "light") {
      setTheme("dark");
    } else {
      setTheme("light");
    }

    const value = useMemo(() => [theme, toggleTheme], [theme, toggleTheme]);

    return <SelectThemeContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</SelectThemeContext.Provider>
}

const useSelectThemeContext = () => useContext(WordsContext);

export { useSelectThemeContext, SelectThemeProvider }
```

Fix your App.tsx to something like this (wrap the content with `SelectThemeProvider`):

```
import { useSelectThemeContext } from './SelectThemeProvider';

const App = () => {
  
  const [theme] = useSelectThemeContext();

  return (
    <SelectThemeProvider>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <GlobalStyles />
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar/>
          <button onClick={toggleTheme}></button>
          <div className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1>linusromland.com</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
    </SelectThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

To switch theme in Navbar:

```
import { useSelectThemeContext } from './SelectThemeProvider';

class Navbar extends React.Component {
  const [,toggleTheme] = useSelectThemeContext();
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Navbar" data-testid="Navbar">
        <BSNavbar bg="light" expand="lg">
          <Container className="col-5">
            <BSNavbar.Brand href="/">Linus Romland</BSNavbar.Brand>
            <BSNavbar.Toggle />
            <BSNavbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
              <Nav>
                <Nav.Link href="/" className="text-dark">
                  Home
                </Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link
                  href="https://github.com/linusromland/"
                  className="text-dark"
                >
                  GitHub
                </Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/about" className="text-dark">
                  About
                </Nav.Link>
                // Here! Just pass toggleTheme function to onClick
                <Button variant="light" onClick={toggleTheme}>
                  <img src={lightmode} alt="Darkmode/Lightmode change" />
                </Button>
              </Nav>
            </BSNavbar.Collapse>
          </Container>
        </BSNavbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Point of the story: You don't have to pass your function for theme toggling down the component tree. Simply import `useSelectThemeContext` in any component which is wrapped by `SelectThemeProvider` and use `toggleTheme` function to toggle the theme.